# How to assign entity and PK in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, primary-key

I have a bit of question. I'm currently being tasked to create a budget tracking database for the IT department using Microsoft Access. So below is the data about the IT department's budget in 2017. There are 14 IT departments in the company and they are categorized as KSIT, OPDR, PIIT and etc. The budget they spend on every year is listed on the left-hand side, which are **perkakasan, perisian, projek baru** and so on.

[EXCEL spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY5Ek.jpg)

So now, my boss would like it if the interface would be something like each department may input the amount they've spent on each category; either perkakasan (hardware), perisian (software), projek baru (new project) and etc. There will be a login page too so there will be an admin ID, password, and the department they're from.

So now, the problem lies in the tables I have to construct. In my mind, I had come up with something like this: there would be 4 tables; table_dept, table_type, table_budget, and table_admin. Now for table_admin, I have no problem constructing them and assigning the PK. The problem is with the other tables. Is it possible that there will be only one entity in table_dept, which is dept_type or something like that. And the values from the dept_type will be the 14 departments, so it will be like a drop-down menu to ease the user inputting the data.

This sounds like a very basic question and I am a noob, I know. Your help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: What is type? Wouldn't the 14 departments be in table_dept?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was going to do. Like just list all the 14 departments under table_dept, but how would I assign PK to that list? It doesn't seem doable? I don't know. That's the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: table_Dept would be a lookup table? Could just use autonumber field as primary key.

Comment: Ah yes! Alright thank you so much for your help!